# Flask session csrf_token missing after closing tab in icognito mode

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, csrf-token

I have noticed the following:

When I go into incognito mode, login to my flask app, logout, close the tab and reopen the incognito mode and try to log back in I get a csrf error saying that the token is missing, and indeed I checked with the following code:

```
log.error(session['csrf_token'])
```

The Server is hosted on eu.pythonanywhere.com and when I reload (restart) the server, it's working again and the procedure can start again

Implemented is the form like this:

```
<form action="" method="post" novalidate>
                    {{ form.csrf_token }}
                    <p>
                        {{ form.username.label }}<br>
                        {{ form.username(size=32, autocomplete="username") }}
                        {% for error in form.username.errors %}
                            <br>
                            <span style="color: red;">{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        {{ form.password.label }}<br>
                        {{ form.password(size=32, autocomplete="current-password") }}
                        {% for error in form.password.errors %}
                            <br>
                            <span style="color: red;">{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </p>

                    <p>{{ form.remember_me() }} {{ form.remember_me.label }}</p>

                    <p>{{ form.submit() }}</p>
                </form>
```

And my app is protected by flask_wtf with this line:

`csrf = CSRFProtect(app)`

And this is the config I'm using, None values get replaced with actual values at runtime

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') or 'censored'
WTF_CSRF_SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') or 'censored'
WTF_CSRF_TIME_LIMIT = 3600
CSRF_ENABLED = True
SERVER_NAME = None
PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME = timedelta(seconds=120)
SESSION_TYPE = "filesystem"
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None
TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

I have searched on so many sites and so many stackoverflow post but never found a solution, is this a bug in Flask?

Flask version: 1.1.1

FlaskWTF version: 0.14.2